# How to pass user informations to a template using Symfony2 and FosUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using symfony2, I installed FosUserBundle and I created a bundle UserBundle as indicated in the FosUserBundle online docs. so far so good.
I also created another controller and I'm able to access the logged user information in this way:

```
$user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

now imagine that in my website, for all the pages/controller, I need to display some user information, even a simple "Welcome MyUser" at the top of the page (so in base.html.twig). I don't want to replicate the line above in all the controllers, so where is the best place to get this information once and pass them to the base template?

Answer (score 0):

For the example you gave, "Welcome MyUser" , you can get this var in twig template with

```
 {% if is_granted("ROLE") %}
    Hi {{ app.user.username }}
{% endif %}
```

This is, if you don't need logic

Also if you didn't knew it you can use heritage in twig, so that you can create a navbar.html.twig with this fosuser var in it, and then in all your templates do

```
{% extends "AcmeMyBundle::navbar.html.twig" %}
{% block body %}
   ....
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: good thanks. what's if I need logic? for example, if in the same place I'd need to display the number of unread email...

Comment: Ha. then you're in the same case as me. I created a service for it, but I still need to call the service in every controller, since you can't do controller heritage, but only template heritage. I'd happy to hear a solution though, but imo not possible.

Comment: A trick you could do is store the number of unread email in user entity, and then in twig do {{ app.user.unreadEmail }}